# Javascript Displaying <div> Style Before and After alert()

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to display a div on my webpage, show an alert, then hide the same  after the alert. I am not sure if it is a Chrome rendering issue, but I cannot get these two separate stylings to display separately. They seem to be executing simultaneously and effectively showing nothing on-screen. I've been digging through websites for a while and cannot seem to find any help. Here is where I am in my javascript file:

```
var hide = document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = 'block';
alert("hello");
hide = document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = 'none';
```

"overlay" is never displayed as a 'block'...however if you comment out the display to 'none', the alert pops up and THEN the  appears as a 'block' element (which lead me to my earlier conclusion of a Chrome rendering issue).

Any help is appreciated. Different ways to work around this to achieve the same outcome (specifically in Chrome) are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a start, don't try to assign the result of an assignment to something *else* unless you're *really* sure of what you're doing (and even then, linting should probably warn you against it)

Comment: Chrome does not immediately re-render the page, which means when the page *is* re-rendered, the div is already set to not display again. Firefox behaves as you expect, btw.

Comment: @trinadh No, OP is (not unreasonably) expecting the `alert` to *block*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is tricky...but a solution however.

```js
var hide = document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = 'block';

setTimeout(function(){
  alert("hello");
  hide = document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = 'none';
},10)
```

```html
<span id="overlay" style="display:none;">this is what to show hide</span>
```

Comment: PERFECT. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The alert event should block page rendering, so call it in a timeout event is a great idea